# FabricJS in Vaadin 12 project

Tags: vaadin, fabricjs

I want to use FabricJS to draw shapes in an existing vaadin 12 project, but the shapes not showing.

test-design-1.html file:

```
    <div id="divCanvas">
        <canvas id="c" height="800px" width="800px"> </canvas>
    </div>
```

TestDesign1.java file:

```
@Tag("test-design-1")
@JavaScript("src/views/js/jquery.min.js")
@JavaScript("src/views/js/fabric.js")
@JavaScript("src/views/js/1.js")
@HtmlImport("src/views/test-design-1.html")
```

1.js file:

```
    window.onload = function() {
        let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
        alert('Objects count: ' + canvas._objects.length); //0

        let rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            width:190,
            height:240,
            strokeWidth: 1,
            stroke:'red',
            fill:'green'
        });
        canvas.add(rect);
        alert('Objects count: ' + canvas._objects.length);  //1
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
```

After running, "Objects count: 1" pop up, but the rectangle shape not showing.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle with the entire code? I made an exemple here: http://jsfiddle.net/4obnpdLh/3/ and everything is ok

Comment: html + javascript runs properly. My problem is to run those code inside a vaadin project. According to those code, "Objects count: 1" pop up means the rectangle has been added to the canvas, but the shape not showing in browser(Chrome, IE and Edge)